# ajax and php and sql

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a list of items on my page from a DB table
I am trying to change the glyphicon when checked

```
<div  class="div1">
<span  id=".<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="color:black;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> </span>
</div>
```

this is the script on the top of my page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").click(function(){
        $(".div1").load("clicked.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

clicked.php looks like:

```
<span  id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="color:black;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span>
```

The problom is the when I click on one item - all the items change there glyphicons

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because your jquery selector, your should select id element.

Comment: @lighter His selector is right.

Comment: `$(this).load("clicked.php");`: Limit the scope of your change to the clicked element.

Comment: Replace `$(".div1").load("clicked.php");` with `$(this).load("clicked.php");` and let us know if it works.

Comment: You dont need to load a new piece of HTML from the server to do this, all you need to do is change the spans `class` to remove `glyphicon-eye-open` and replace it with `glyphicon-ok`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman & jeroen It worked like magic!!!!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Thanks,
how can I  make the next click reverce it back to the first class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go all the way to the server to get a new span when all you are doing is removing a class and adding a new class to a span.

Also using the right scope, `$(this)` will stop it effecting all your `div1` elements.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").click(function(){
        //$(".div1").load("clicked.php");
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
        $(this).children('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    });
});
</script>
```

And to make the code toggle from one to another on each click

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".div1").click(function(){
            if ( $(this).children('span').hasClass('glyphicon-ok') ) {
                $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
                $(this).children('span').addClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
            } else {
                $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
                $(this).children('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove & add new class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").click(function(){
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
        $(this).children('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok');

        //Here you can add ajax call

    });
});
```